# Different between Utilizations for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

**Based upon this:** Reserved Instances can be purchased for 1 or 3 year terms, and the one-time fee per instance is non-refundable. Light and Medium Utilization Reserved Instances also are billed by the instance-hour for the time that instances are in a running state; if you do not run the instance in an hour, there is zero usage charge. Partial instance-hours consumed are billed as full hours. Heavy Utilization Reserved Instances are billed for every hour during the entire Reserved Instance term (which means you’re charged the hourly fee regardless of whether any usage has occurred during an hour).

Why would I ever buy the heavy utilization package when I could use the light package and save money whenever the server is'nt being used??

Comment: Uh - because if your server isn't running for more than an hour, it's not being heavily used ?  You should realize that Amazon will charge you for every hour that the server is running, even if it isn't doing anything; you'll have to actually shut it down for at least an hour to be able to use the lower-utilization pricing schemes.

Comment: @gareth_bowles I don't understand your comment. If amazon is charging for every hour that the server is running regardless of traffic, why do they need to specify for a Heavy Utilization that your being charged hourly fees regardless of whether usage has occured. I would prefer you simply answer my question instead of arguing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apologies for my previous comment, which does seem argumentative now I read it again.  Hopefully this answer will make up for it.

With the 3 different packages for reserved instances, Amazon is giving you a tradeoff between what you pay up front for the reserved instance and how much you pay per instance hour for running instances.  The up front cost is lowest for Light Utilization instances and lowest for Heavy Utilization instances, but it's the other way around for the hourly cost; that is lowest for Heavy Utilization and highest for Light Utilization.

Let's do some math to illustrate, using a Small Linux instance with a one year reservation term. Here are the relative prices:

Up front payment: $69 for Light, $195 for Heavy

Hourly cost: $0.039c for Light, $0.016c for Heavy

Let's say you run your instances for only 1 hour per day, or 365 hours during the 1 year reservation period.  Your total cost would be:

Light: $69.00 + (365 * $0.039) = **$83.24**

Heavy: $195.00 + (365 * $0.016) = **$200.84**

But when we run the instances for 20 hours a day or 7300 hours overall, we get:

Light: $69.00 + (7300 * $0.039) = **$353.70**

Heavy: $195.00 + (7300 * $0.016) = **$311.80**

So if you predict your workload carefully, you can make some significant savings by choosing the right pricing scheme.

Comment: This is not correct: Heavy instances are charged for *every* hour, whether the machine is on or not.  So the cost for the heavy instance will be:

Comment: Wow, I had to look that up because it just didn't seem reasonable, but you are right.

Why on earth wouldn't they just charge per year then, without an hourly charge?  Leave it to Amazon to complicate the heck out of this.

Comment: @Nate That's a question everyone has, and the answer I received from their accounts team makes sense. It all has to do with the complicated accounting scheme on the finance side- it is entirely dependent on line item charges per product code per hour, so the reserved instance product had to fit into this billing paradigm.

Answer (score 7):

@gareth_bowles answer has one error -- Heavy Utilization instances are charged for **every** hour, regardless of whether the machine is on or not.

The cost for different Utilization rates looks like:

```
Heavy:    $195 + (365 * 24 * $0.016) = $335.16       (independent of hours used)
Medium:   $160 + (365 *  N * $0.024) = $160 + 8.76N  (use N hours / day)
Light:     $69 + (365 *  N * $0.039) = $69 + 14.235N (use N hours / day)
On-Demand:  $0 + (365 *  N * $0.080) = $29.2N        (use N hours / day)
```

The break-even usage points are:

```
Heavy:     > 80% utilization (20   hrs / day)
Medium:    < 80% utilization (20   hrs / day)
Light:     < 70% utilization (16.6 hrs / day)
On-Demand: < 20% utilization ( 4.6 hrs / day)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on that one - they do make it complicated !

Comment: Billing for every hour for Heavy Utilization was not obvious - search for "billed for every hour" on http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/