# Break even points for on-demand vs 3yr reserved seem to disqualify light use entirely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is a follow-up question of sorts on [this other Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001320/what-is-the-difference-between-a-light-medium-or-heavy-utilization-reserved-ins).
As of today, EC2 pricing on AWS for m3.medium instances for the Oregon region is:

- On Demand: $0.077 per hour
- Reserved 3yr Light Use: $172 upfront plus $0.050 per hour
- Reserved 3yr Medium Use: $286 upfront plus $0.022 per hour
- Reserved 3yr Heavy Use: $337 upfront plus $0.015 per hour

Assuming 8765 hours per year, at the end of the three years, the break-even points based on rate of usage seem to be:

- On Demand vs Light Use: 24%
- Light Use vs Medium Use: 15%
- On Demand vs Medium Use: 20%
- Medium Use vs Heavy Use: 77%

By that math, it therefore seems that I'm always better off using On Demand that Reserved-Light Use. This seems... counter-intuitive? In the sense that if this is the case, why is Amazon offering the Reserved-Light Use option.

So... is my math wrong? If not, am I missing something? What would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you compare the pricing for any possible number of hours of utilization, from 1 hour per month to ~730 hours per month, you'll find there's no number of hours where light utilization reserved instances are the lowest possible cost.

However, it's a bit more complicated than just that one factor.

If you rank the instance classes by cost at each hour of utilization (dividing the monthly amortized cost of the up-front charge by the number of running hours) you should see the point -- between 24% and 42% utilization, "light" instances are cheaper than both on-demand and heavy instances, and between 42% and 100% utilization, light instances are still cheaper than on-demand instances, even though medium and heavy are less expensive than light.

Below 15% utilization, you'll pay less per hour for a light than for a medium, but more than an on-demand instance -- so your cost for a reserved instance that you use very little or none at all is better on light than on medium at extremely low utilization.

In the long run, absent any consideration of the "time value of money," the medium instance is a better deal than the light one, assuming you absolutely know you'll have it running at least 15% of the time.

But still, at any utilization level above 24%, a light utilization reserved instance is less expensive than an on-demand instance, so if your utilization is light (24% to 42%), you get a better hourly cost than an on-demand instance, for a smaller up-front cost than medium, with a slightly reduced burden compared to medium if your reserved instance is used very little or not at all.

I'll assume you've made a note of the fact that heavy instances are very different than light and medium, because in exchange for the deep discounts, you pay for all the hours in a month on a heavy instance, whether it's running or not.

Comment: Is it fair to summarize your answer as: "for light-ish loads (24% to 42%), Reserved-Light Use might be attractive because it is cheaper than On-Demand, but calls for a smaller upfront cost than Reserved-Medium Use"?